# No se como calcular el promedio de un grupo de alumnos. Lengaje C

Tags: c

Un promedio simple general los se calcular, solo debo dividir el total de las notas entre el total de alumnos, pero en este programa las notas están seccionadas por letras y en serio no logro ver como calcular el promedio.

Y a hice el programa, el detalle es que al final se me pide que presente las notas de la siguiente forma, ejemplo:

- 8 Alumnos sacaron A
- 4 Alumnos sacaron B
- 1 Alumnos sacaron C
- 3 Alumnos sacaron D
- 5 Alumnos sacaron F

Ahora me piden que calcule el promedio general de los alumnos pero no logro ver la formula ya que las notas están expresadas en Letras y no números.

Comment: Para calcular el promedio suma todo y divide entre la cantidad de valores.

Comment: ¿cómo lo harías en papel, sin un programa? Si no sabes responder esa pregunta, el problema que tienes no es de programación, sino de ignorancia del procedimiento. Si alguien te está dando las especificaciones de este programa, esta persona debe resolverte la duda. Si estas haciendo el programa para un sistema escolar específico, investiga cómo realizarlo en la documentación de ese sistema. TIP: Usualmente cada letra tiene una equivalencia numérica, que es la que utilizas para sacar el promedio. No hay un estándar mundial, varía de un país a otro, incluso a veces de un distrito escolar a otro.

Comment: Si las notas estarían expresadas en números (del 1 al 100, del 1 al 10, del 1 al 20, etc) seria fácil verlos. Sumo todas las notas, ejemplo me de 476 y los divido entre el numero de alumnos y me da el promedio.

Pero al ser letras las notas (A, B, C,  D, F) sencillamente no se como sumarlas para dividirlas entre el numero de estudiantes. El programa es un ejerció del libro "Como programar en C, C++, y Java" de Dietel y Dietel. Los estoy haciendo todos.

En serio si no vas a ayudar y solo vas a insultar, no escribas nada..

Comment: A=10,B=9,C=8,D=7,F=6. Convierte, suma, calcula el promedio y luego usa la misma tabla para convertir de vuelta a letra.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías traducir las calificaciones de letras en número, por ejemplo, si un estudiante sacó una A, entonces sería 100 o 10 en números, saca el promedio con los números, y después traduce el promedio resultante a una letra (de los valores anteriormente asignados.

O ya bien, puede ser la cantidad de letras, un valor, por ejemplo, A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, ..., y así sucesivamente, y realiza lo mismo, saca el promedio con números, y finalmente traduce el valor numérico a una letra.

:)